# OpenSearch Polygon Search

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I'm having an issue regarding polygon search in AWS OpenSearch specific coordinates is not able search within the polygon however if slightly change the coordinates then it is able to search.

**Polygon:**

```
"location": {
    "type": "polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          73.04709959305895,
          33.596549080302886
        ],
        [
          73.05538062994731,
          33.590042966660526
        ],
        [
          73.05705400009572,
          33.589184980987284
        ],
        [
          73.06061527502699,
          33.58829123683749
        ],
        [
          73.06241736595608,
          33.586753975242246
        ],
        [
          73.06409073610449,
          33.58164148968145
        ],
        [
          73.06494887464216,
          33.578423686118235
        ],
        [
          73.06520631620346,
          33.575456049825625
        ],
        [
          73.06576410625293,
          33.57384704773411
        ],
        [
          73.0630450803049,
          33.573946492885064
        ],
        [
          73.06184368635218,
          33.574518585294626
        ],
        [
          73.06074955971668,
          33.5743755625477
        ],
        [
          73.05946235191017,
          33.57403588257397
        ],
        [
          73.05804642332308,
          33.57401800464362
        ],
        [
          73.05729555210264,
          33.57401800464362
        ],
        [
          73.05611561161336,
          33.575180062416706
        ],
        [
          73.05592253044239,
          33.57539459444878
        ],
        [
          73.05469968302621,
          33.575323083830675
        ],
        [
          73.05405607912297,
          33.57507279620072
        ],
        [
          73.05341247521972,
          33.575913044658364
        ],
        [
          73.0524685228283,
          33.57684267171891
        ],
        [
          73.05208236048637,
          33.57639573688179
        ],
        [
          73.05143875658311,
          33.57618120733798
        ],
        [
          73.05105259424117,
          33.57569851391482
        ],
        [
          73.05010864184975,
          33.575680636328805
        ],
        [
          73.0494006775562,
          33.57496552985144
        ],
        [
          73.049100329068,
          33.57496552985144
        ],
        [
          73.04888579443363,
          33.57466160780459
        ],
        [
          73.04751277277337,
          33.57430405108535
        ],
        [
          73.04725533121207,
          33.57383922513616
        ],
        [
          73.04701934311421,
          33.573749835243596
        ],
        [
          73.04656882038194,
          33.573946492885064
        ],
        [
          73.04579649569806,
          33.57362468923849
        ],
        [
          73.0453459729658,
          33.573749835243596
        ],
        [
          73.04483108984319,
          33.573499543051945
        ],
        [
          73.04330789393886,
          33.57369620126362
        ],
        [
          73.0433722543292,
          33.5733565186166
        ],
        [
          73.04281446427973,
          33.573177737739194
        ],
        [
          73.04244975540118,
          33.57330288439226
        ],
        [
          73.04223522076681,
          33.5730525909047
        ],
        [
          73.04247120886463,
          33.57285593122681
        ],
        [
          73.04210649998613,
          33.57260563644331
        ],
        [
          73.04223522076681,
          33.5723195843736
        ],
        [
          73.0419348722786,
          33.57228382779822
        ],
        [
          73.04214940691303,
          33.57183686935659
        ],
        [
          73.04182760496143,
          33.57178323418808
        ],
        [
          73.04178469803453,
          33.57133627315468
        ],
        [
          73.04141998915604,
          33.5708893098072
        ],
        [
          73.04141998915604,
          33.570227799806176
        ],
        [
          73.04141998915604,
          33.56994173985752
        ],
        [
          73.04298609198725,
          33.56960204243743
        ],
        [
          73.04386568398833,
          33.569745073092996
        ],
        [
          73.0480062024325,
          33.57106809542386
        ],
        [
          73.04922904984868,
          33.570084769950334
        ],
        [
          73.05062352497238,
          33.56963780012355
        ],
        [
          73.05082514393214,
          33.569578295643765
        ],
        [
          73.05237515666579,
          33.56766523732035
        ],
        [
          73.05262060783062,
          33.56766719351819
        ],
        [
          73.0541116235398,
          33.56764931426892
        ],
        [
          73.0551628432484,
          33.56804265689768
        ],
        [
          73.05604243524951,
          33.56842705818997
        ],
        [
          73.05856321720388,
          33.569160097771125
        ],
        [
          73.05995769232754,
          33.56958025179827
        ],
        [
          73.0607729975902,
          33.5682750856347
        ],
        [
          73.06100898568802,
          33.568257206511305
        ],
        [
          73.06101971241976,
          33.566996718980825
        ],
        [
          73.0611913401273,
          33.56697883959271
        ],
        [
          73.06136296783481,
          33.566764286646624
        ],
        [
          73.06155604900579,
          33.56678216607915
        ],
        [
          73.06148096188375,
          33.56604910630935
        ],
        [
          73.06197439154293,
          33.56491374535796
        ],
        [
          73.06329377954454,
          33.56536967950223
        ],
        [
          73.06297197759294,
          33.56600440734157
        ],
        [
          73.06349758744726,
          33.56690732200325
        ],
        [
          73.0639481101795,
          33.56733642665144
        ],
        [
          73.06454880715586,
          33.56809629423416
        ],
        [
          73.0649349694978,
          33.568543272041325
        ],
        [
          73.06498860315642,
          33.569347826263034
        ],
        [
          73.06495642296125,
          33.5696607064356
        ],
        [
          73.0648169754489,
          33.5702685846723
        ],
        [
          73.0649349694978,
          33.57033116013015
        ],
        [
          73.06600764266989,
          33.56949085733975
        ],
        [
          73.0661685436457,
          33.56924055279997
        ],
        [
          73.06635089808493,
          33.568266146073476
        ],
        [
          73.06673706042689,
          33.56737218527587
        ],
        [
          73.06694086832958,
          33.567014598365205
        ],
        [
          73.06694086832958,
          33.566755346928964
        ],
        [
          73.0669086881344,
          33.56652291394504
        ],
        [
          73.06683360101236,
          33.566326239393
        ],
        [
          73.06673706042689,
          33.566084865466905
        ],
        [
          73.06649034559732,
          33.56576303251584
        ],
        [
          73.06547130608385,
          33.564243249596174
        ],
        [
          73.06349758744726,
          33.5649495049857
        ],
        [
          73.06330685577991,
          33.56528726443578
        ],
        [
          73.06319958846268,
          33.56526491475763
        ],
        [
          73.0619660143148,
          33.564822389938605
        ],
        [
          73.06086173648428,
          33.564361982320435
        ],
        [
          73.05956916531193,
          33.5639552129137
        ],
        [
          73.05919909306756,
          33.56378982260698
        ],
        [
          73.05852330896917,
          33.563414340734795
        ],
        [
          73.05839995155436,
          33.563329410084926
        ],
        [
          73.05835704462747,
          33.5631863688016
        ],
        [
          73.05831413770062,
          33.56300309681106
        ],
        [
          73.058298047603,
          33.562913695698924
        ],
        [
          73.05820150701751,
          33.56278406392194
        ],
        [
          73.05811032979791,
          33.56264102173534
        ],
        [
          73.05819078028583,
          33.56256503047731
        ],
        [
          73.05906500892107,
          33.561822994678764
        ],
        [
          73.0592741801896,
          33.56167101065625
        ],
        [
          73.05944044453126,
          33.56141174317701
        ],
        [
          73.05983733360495,
          33.560928967176096
        ],
        [
          73.06071692560602,
          33.559874002819356
        ],
        [
          73.06196658985152,
          33.558327294492415
        ],
        [
          73.0614838869241,
          33.5575852222839
        ],
        [
          73.06066329194744,
          33.55674926583455
        ],
        [
          73.059681795995,
          33.55576577730097
        ],
        [
          73.05917227623826,
          33.55512650374947
        ],
        [
          73.05801378921242,
          33.553901588762606
        ],
        [
          73.05711810711374,
          33.55294936182863
        ],
        [
          73.0568660289183,
          33.552645362287315
        ],
        [
          73.05669976457665,
          33.55245759733035
        ],
        [
          73.05658177052771,
          33.55225642013788
        ],
        [
          73.0564476863812,
          33.5519479475329
        ],
        [
          73.05590062306344,
          33.55032509525478
        ],
        [
          73.05578799238037,
          33.54991378900907
        ],
        [
          73.0554501003312,
          33.54876480357869
        ],
        [
          73.05518729540402,
          33.54822383627642
        ],
        [
          73.05484940335484,
          33.54766945304782
        ],
        [
          73.05455325137657,
          33.54713741907696
        ],
        [
          73.05405982171744,
          33.54633265794496
        ],
        [
          73.05378629005855,
          33.54587215237024
        ],
        [
          73.05364147918034,
          33.54548765069003
        ],
        [
          73.05358784552172,
          33.545273044357174
        ],
        [
          73.05358248215589,
          33.54496901780663
        ],
        [
          73.05361466235104,
          33.54351146389997
        ],
        [
          73.0536039356193,
          33.542241672975706
        ],
        [
          73.05374338313166,
          33.54154417424783
        ],
        [
          73.05388283064404,
          33.54096739220164
        ],
        [
          73.05417245240051,
          33.54011339001037
        ],
        [
          73.05435480683977,
          33.5394918857286
        ],
        [
          73.05454252464487,
          33.53873623781233
        ],
        [
          73.05463370186449,
          33.5380163540672
        ],
        [
          73.05466051869381,
          33.53731434985877
        ],
        [
          73.05467124542551,
          33.536764368056616
        ],
        [
          73.05466051869381,
          33.5363440544017
        ],
        [
          73.0545800682059,
          33.536035524992684
        ],
        [
          73.054306536547,
          33.5357895949649
        ],
        [
          73.05346985147278,
          33.535127816143124
        ],
        [
          73.05278870400855,
          33.53453310517732
        ],
        [
          73.05268143669133,
          33.534385544680156
        ],
        [
          73.05311050596015,
          33.53418879695881
        ],
        [
          73.05420999596153,
          33.533620908979
        ],
        [
          73.05481069293788,
          33.533298955081605
        ],
        [
          73.0552558523043,
          33.53313350608462
        ],
        [
          73.05680181941865,
          33.532906855523095
        ],
        [
          73.05667309863803,
          33.53262067197655
        ],
        [
          73.05598658780788,
          33.532692217952
        ],
        [
          73.05540734429496,
          33.53233448748269
        ],
        [
          73.05386269492719,
          33.52945470328904
        ],
        [
          73.05321909102395,
          33.52652115990949
        ],
        [
          73.05248967326695,
          33.52448193088005
        ],
        [
          73.05279002175514,
          33.52399894854067
        ],
        [
          73.05716652829715,
          33.524320937066605
        ],
        [
          73.05808902722517,
          33.52424938416445
        ],
        [
          73.05830356185957,
          33.523319191049225
        ],
        [
          73.05974094391013,
          33.52346229833351
        ],
        [
          73.05993402508109,
          33.52228165615651
        ],
        [
          73.06272297532847,
          33.522388987929475
        ],
        [
          73.06952372323939,
          33.523301302622045
        ],
        [
          73.06855833001055,
          33.52507223896363
        ],
        [
          73.06815071420519,
          33.52534055948852
        ],
        [
          73.06764170116368,
          33.525634309205905
        ],
        [
          73.06672456560155,
          33.52635876800399
        ],
        [
          73.06613459535693,
          33.52756618584736
        ],
        [
          73.0649439281359,
          33.527615376587306
        ],
        [
          73.06489565784318,
          33.52769139858486
        ],
        [
          73.06493856477007,
          33.52817883215763
        ],
        [
          73.06523891325824,
          33.529287845094935
        ],
        [
          73.06521209642895,
          33.52943541429259
        ],
        [
          73.06513164594104,
          33.529502491117356
        ],
        [
          73.06483129745284,
          33.52963217283101
        ],
        [
          73.0649065013657,
          33.52964111635948
        ],
        [
          73.06502449541463,
          33.529596398553785
        ],
        [
          73.06517466965872,
          33.529529321801874
        ],
        [
          73.06526584687838,
          33.52943094247162
        ],
        [
          73.06527657361006,
          33.529359393797485
        ],
        [
          73.06503522214634,
          33.52834876245123
        ],
        [
          73.06660668834343,
          33.528599185478555
        ],
        [
          73.06841414263837,
          33.52884066413945
        ],
        [
          73.0681513377112,
          33.52975291077258
        ],
        [
          73.07010481015317,
          33.52945470216923
        ],
        [
          73.07186399415536,
          33.53006286334192
        ],
        [
          73.07164945952094,
          33.530706794038906
        ],
        [
          73.07128475064243,
          33.532155620573185
        ],
        [
          73.07149928527686,
          33.53254912482209
        ],
        [
          73.07167091298439,
          33.533783285621745
        ],
        [
          73.07214288918011,
          33.53485645460502
        ],
        [
          73.07207852878977,
          33.53886283443476
        ],
        [
          73.07222870303384,
          33.54088383951067
        ],
        [
          73.07203562186288,
          33.54349497963664
        ],
        [
          73.07154219220374,
          33.54617757568627
        ],
        [
          73.07137056449622,
          33.546821386346885
        ],
        [
          73.07111312293492,
          33.547536725899576
        ],
        [
          73.07025498439725,
          33.54805534337222
        ],
        [
          73.06967574088434,
          33.54837724230686
        ],
        [
          73.06937539239617,
          33.54866337368648
        ],
        [
          73.06939684585961,
          33.5494681131116
        ],
        [
          73.06937539239617,
          33.54998671899183
        ],
        [
          73.06875324195636,
          33.55277640755733
        ],
        [
          73.06802382419937,
          33.55438580229287
        ],
        [
          73.0685172538585,
          33.554564622079376
        ],
        [
          73.06916085776176,
          33.55433215628475
        ],
        [
          73.06937539239617,
          33.554743441495695
        ],
        [
          73.070533879422,
          33.55431427427461
        ],
        [
          73.07135106385928,
          33.55789060127506
        ],
        [
          73.0691413571248,
          33.55815881993305
        ],
        [
          73.06922717097859,
          33.55874889804881
        ],
        [
          73.06830467205059,
          33.558874065615704
        ],
        [
          73.06830467205059,
          33.55941049599079
        ],
        [
          73.06963478678398,
          33.560572750373915
        ],
        [
          73.0709434480539,
          33.5615025426192
        ],
        [
          73.07139397078616,
          33.561985315413786
        ],
        [
          73.07208048161627,
          33.56230716244422
        ],
        [
          73.0726597251292,
          33.56114493140179
        ],
        [
          73.07287425976361,
          33.56123433434497
        ],
        [
          73.08036151850465,
          33.56141313995368
        ],
        [
          73.0803400650412,
          33.56184227190415
        ],
        [
          73.08036151850465,
          33.56209259789054
        ],
        [
          73.08109093626165,
          33.56302237377305
        ],
        [
          73.08156291245737,
          33.56395213964518
        ],
        [
          73.07937465918634,
          33.56473885679505
        ],
        [
          73.07907431069815,
          33.56397001966
        ],
        [
          73.07791582367231,
          33.563451497727144
        ],
        [
          73.07776564942823,
          33.56284357149613
        ],
        [
          73.07731512669595,
          33.56266476884902
        ],
        [
          73.07639262776799,
          33.56377333929336
        ],
        [
          73.07497669918084,
          33.564846135851084
        ],
        [
          73.07431164181419,
          33.56502493398163
        ],
        [
          73.07341059634963,
          33.56497129458133
        ],
        [
          73.07285280630016,
          33.56534676968364
        ],
        [
          73.07259536473886,
          33.56568648384558
        ],
        [
          73.07253100434855,
          33.56606195583805
        ],
        [
          73.07231646971414,
          33.56609771499028
        ],
        [
          73.07210193507971,
          33.565883159854785
        ],
        [
          73.0712223430786,
          33.56600831708195
        ],
        [
          73.07105071537109,
          33.56489977532912
        ],
        [
          73.0706430995657,
          33.56407729967116
        ],
        [
          73.06785414931835,
          33.562342923151334
        ],
        [
          73.06766106814737,
          33.56275417021886
        ],
        [
          73.06785414931835,
          33.56320117567973
        ],
        [
          73.06607351185271,
          33.56439913890504
        ],
        [
          73.06602267067956,
          33.56446032175262
        ],
        [
          73.06597440038679,
          33.56449161159198
        ],
        [
          73.06640346965563,
          33.56516657536676
        ],
        [
          73.06697198643684,
          33.565975630952494
        ],
        [
          73.06706852702233,
          33.566190185858254
        ],
        [
          73.06712216068092,
          33.56629299322829
        ],
        [
          73.06718115770539,
          33.56650307747346
        ],
        [
          73.06718115770539,
          33.566605884470995
        ],
        [
          73.06717043097365,
          33.56702158108243
        ],
        [
          73.06711143394918,
          33.567236133389194
        ],
        [
          73.06697734980267,
          33.56754455139613
        ],
        [
          73.0666501844852,
          33.56838040335452
        ],
        [
          73.06695589633922,
          33.56852790580134
        ],
        [
          73.06710607058335,
          33.56833570559362
        ],
        [
          73.06722942799811,
          33.56840275222631
        ],
        [
          73.06688617258305,
          33.56869328703294
        ],
        [
          73.06737423887635,
          33.569046397250965
        ],
        [
          73.06693980624166,
          33.56963640097511
        ],
        [
          73.06653755380214,
          33.56987329527535
        ],
        [
          73.06628011224082,
          33.56963640097511
        ],
        [
          73.06617284492363,
          33.56973920424185
        ],
        [
          73.06575986575238,
          33.57006549206021
        ],
        [
          73.06559896477658,
          33.570195112906084
        ],
        [
          73.06519671233704,
          33.570449884346324
        ],
        [
          73.06493927077577,
          33.57069571572508
        ],
        [
          73.06486418365373,
          33.5707359426113
        ],
        [
          73.06477300643407,
          33.57082980527298
        ],
        [
          73.0647569163365,
          33.57101753029016
        ],
        [
          73.06471400940961,
          33.57147343220387
        ],
        [
          73.06473009950723,
          33.57158964211055
        ],
        [
          73.06484809355615,
          33.571746078276334
        ],
        [
          73.06486954701955,
          33.571839939839755
        ],
        [
          73.065121625215,
          33.57210364559084
        ],
        [
          73.06540588360562,
          33.572371820104784
        ],
        [
          73.06551851428868,
          33.57254166353273
        ],
        [
          73.06570086872792,
          33.57293051433315
        ],
        [
          73.06580277267926,
          33.57356518658968
        ],
        [
          73.06580277267926,
          33.57366351567677
        ],
        [
          73.06581349941102,
          33.573878051477955
        ],
        [
          73.06526107272738,
          33.575437889500606
        ],
        [
          73.06500363116606,
          33.57842787269409
        ],
        [
          73.06415621936014,
          33.581672490625515
        ],
        [
          73.06304498307487,
          33.585904613889326
        ],
        [
          73.06272837298549,
          33.586713475241154
        ],
        [
          73.06225639678975,
          33.58723185745537
        ],
        [
          73.06155379586207,
          33.58774129901076
        ],
        [
          73.0606473870317,
          33.58837139361547
        ],
        [
          73.05851813078513,
          33.58901488973874
        ],
        [
          73.05700566161251,
          33.5893545107576
        ],
        [
          73.05553609936676,
          33.590140996405154
        ],
        [
          73.05187828385002,
          33.59292491923967
        ],
        [
          73.04750714067383,
          33.59634772529423
        ],
        [
          73.0685590626048,
          33.598240301154725
        ],
        [
          73.0858934610654,
          33.59380770457735
        ],
        [
          73.0953329849796,
          33.58923188207866
        ],
        [
          73.10545901972391,
          33.581652642178994
        ],
        [
          73.10803343533688,
          33.56792251269592
        ],
        [
          73.11043622324232,
          33.54245878638304
        ],
        [
          73.10339948723356,
          33.534159995930274
        ],
        [
          73.08657997189555,
          33.52614661470084
        ],
        [
          73.0635818590864,
          33.52085165182123
        ],
        [
          73.04727722687096,
          33.51913429694721
        ],
        [
          73.0301144561179,
          33.51970675236037
        ],
        [
          73.01913028283592,
          33.52657592180759
        ],
        [
          73.01123540828948,
          33.53902490075991
        ],
        [
          73.00831773726146,
          33.55705127813726
        ],
        [
          73.00814610955395,
          33.568637677516136
        ],
        [
          73.01226517453468,
          33.58336875479968
        ],
        [
          73.03363964951124,
          33.59609554469042
        ],
        [
          73.04709959305895,
          33.596549080302886
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "properties": {
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_shape"
    }
  }
}
```

**Query with not searchable Point:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_shape": {
            "location": {
              "shape": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                  73.1036496,
                  33.5830702
                ]
              },
              "relation": "contains"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Query with searchable Point:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_shape": {
            "location": {
              "shape": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                  73.1014931,
                  33.583173
                ]
              },
              "relation": "contains"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I just changed the coordinates from `33.5830702,73.1036496` to `33.583173,73.1014931`

Answer (score 1):

I took your data and projected into X,Y space and the original point is outside the polygon. If using lat/long values it may give the illusion the point is inside but the polygon requires sides that are straight. That is, each line between adjacent points must be a straight line. When you use lat/lon the line is curved. So maybe you thought the point was inside but its outside.